# Does Thrift catch or block SIGPIPE?

Tags: signals, thrift

Does Thrift **catch** or **block** `SIGPIPE` or any other signals which will terminate a program?

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the server implementation you chose to use, but most of them will:

The best is to test for yourself with a server implementation that fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apache thrift does not catch or block `SIGPIPE` or other signals, and it does not implement a mechanism to do so. As of now, you have to take care of signal handling yourself. This is also reflected in the documentation for the [thrift cpp library](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/cpp#sigpipe-signal).

However, if you use thrift with OpenSSL on Unix/Linux platforms, it is important to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal in both client and server to avoid a potential termination:

> SIGPIPE signal
>
> Applications running OpenSSL over network connections may crash if SIGPIPE is not ignored. This happens when they receive a connection reset by remote peer exception, which somehow triggers a SIGPIPE signal. If not handled, this signal would kill the application.

The recommended way to set a new signal handler is [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), but if you just want to ignore a signal you can use the simpler call to signal:

```cpp
#include <signal.h>

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```